# Updated from 1.7.3 to 2.2.0 Codeigniter - function/code issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I've upgraded my CI to 2.2.0 from 1.7.3 and did the required changes but somehow the script isn't logging me to the website anymore. I have auto login after registration and it works correctly but normally typing ID and password isn't working anymore. It simply do nothing after I type ID and password. What may cause that in this function below? It's the session but what exactly has changed since the older version.

**EDIT2: The session file for version 2.2.0 located in system/libraries/session.php is not working correctly for me but my old 1.7.3 session.php file is working. so something definitely related to the session in the below code. Is it safe to use my old session.php file or I will have to really upgrade it too?**

```
function login_do()
{
    if ( $_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] )
    {
        $user = $this->db->where( array( 'users_name' => trim( $_POST['username'] ), 'users_password' => sha1( md5( $_POST['password'] ) ) ) )->get( 'users' );
        if ( $user->num_rows == '1' )
        {
            $user = $user->row();
            $data = array( 'logged' => true, 'users_id' => $user->users_id );
            if ( $user->users_teams_id > '0' )
            {
                $leader = $this->db->where( array( 'team_leader_id' => $user->users_id, 'teams_id' => $user->users_teams_id ) )->get( 'teams' )->row();
                $data['teams_id'] = $user->users_teams_id;
                if ( $leader )
                    $data['leader_teams_id'] = $user->users_teams_id;
            }

            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            $this->session->unset_userdata( array( 'logged' => false, 'users_id' => false, 'teams_id' => false, 'leader_teams_id' => false ) );
            $this->session->set_userdata( $data );


            $already_logged = $this->db->where( array( 'users_id' => $this->user->id() ) )->get( 'logged_today' );
            if ( $already_logged->num_rows == '0' )
            $this->db->insert( 'logged_today', array( 'users_id' => $this->user->id() ) );
        }
        else
            $this->session->set_flashdata( 'error', 'user_pass' );
    }
    else
        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'error', 'data' );

    redirect( 'home' );
}
```

Comment: have you debug line by line? means upto which line you are getting desired output

Comment: I've updated my main post. Please check

Answer (score 0):

From  [`CodeIgnitor Documentation`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

> This function should be the last one called, and even flash variables
>   will no longer be available. If you only want some items destroyed and
>   not all, use `unset_userdata()`.

also check [changelog](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/changelog.html) for session library